# How to add batch operations in this PDF watermark remover script?

Tags: pdf, python-3.x, watermark

This script, not elaborated by me, allows me to remove a watermark from a PDF file. The problem is that it doesn't have an option to do batch operations, and I have more than 1,000 PDF files in the same directory

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

def removeWatermark(input_fname: str, output_fname: str):

    with open(input_fname, "rb") as inputFile, open(output_fname, "wb") as outputFile:

        reader = PdfFileReader(inputFile)
        writer = PdfFileWriter()

        for n in range(reader.numPages):

            page = reader.getPage(n)
            del page["/Contents"][-1]

            writer.addPage(page)

        writer.write(outputFile)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys

    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        raise RuntimeError("Arguments not correct!")

    removeWatermark(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

If anyone can help me I appreciate.

Dependences: PyPDF2 and PDFtk

I solved the problem:

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
files = os.listdir(path)

def removeWater(inputfilename,outputfilename):

        "input"
        inputFile = open(inputfilename, "rb")
        outputFile = open(outputfilename, "wb")
        
        pdfReader = PdfFileReader(inputFile)
        pdfWriter = PdfFileWriter()
        
        for n in range(pdfReader.numPages):

            page = pdfReader.getPage(n)
            del page["/Contents"][-1]

            pdfWriter.addPage(page)

        pdfWriter.write(outputFile)

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(('.pdf')):
                removeWater(os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".pdf",os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + "- limpo" + ".pdf")
```

Comment: The idea would be a loop of the execution. I'm using Windows. I only have a course in algorithm and C language. I thought it would be easy, but I can't create this loop. Despite having purchased a basic python course the instructor did not go very far in manipulating files

Comment: python invocations can be repeated just as simply as any shell utility in cmd, powershell or bash. So where is the problem?! No need to change the script even a bit, if it runs fine on a single file.

Comment: thanks, but i already solved it. I edited the question

Comment: Write that as an answer and not an edit to the question. You are allowed to self-answer. You were looking to loop all via Python it appears.